# Issues with 2D-Interpolation in Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

In my application, the data data is sampled on a distorted grid, and I would like to resample it to a nondistorted grid. In order to test this, I wrote this program with examplary distortions and a simple function as data:

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as intp
import pylab as plt

# Defining some variables:

quadratic = -3/128
linear = 1/16
pn = np.poly1d([quadratic, linear,0])

pixels_x = 50
pixels_y = 30
frame = np.zeros((pixels_x,pixels_y))

x_width= np.concatenate((np.linspace(8,7.8,57) , np.linspace(7.8,8,pixels_y-57)))

def data(x,y):
    z = y*(np.exp(-(x-5)**2/3) + np.exp(-(x)**2/5) + np.exp(-(x+5)**2))
    return(z)

# Generating grid coordinates

yt = np.arange(380,380+pixels_y*4,4)
xt = np.linspace(-7.8,7.8,pixels_x)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xt,yt)
Y=Y.T
X=X.T

Y_m = np.zeros((pixels_x,pixels_y))
X_m = np.zeros((pixels_x,pixels_y))

# generating distorted grid coordinates:    

for i in range(pixels_y):
    Y_m[:,i] = Y[:,i] - pn(xt)
    X_m[:,i] = np.linspace(-x_width[i],x_width[i],pixels_x)


# Sample data:
for i in range(pixels_y):
    for j in range(pixels_x):
        frame[j,i] = data(X_m[j,i],Y_m[j,i])


Y_m = Y_m.flatten()
X_m = X_m.flatten()
frame = frame.flatten()
##
Y = Y.flatten()
X = X.flatten()
ipf = intp.interp2d(X_m,Y_m,frame)
interpolated_frame = ipf(xt,yt)
```

At this point, I have to questions:

1. The code works, but I get the the following warning:

   Warning:     No more knots can be added because the number of B-spline coefficients
   already exceeds the number of data points m. Probably causes: either
   s or m too small. (fp>s)
   kx,ky=1,1 nx,ny=54,31 m=1500 fp=0.000006 s=0.000000

Also, some interpolation artifacts appear, and I assume that they are related to the warning - Do you guys know what I am doing wrong?

1. For my actual applications, the frames need to be around 500*100, but when doing this, I get a MemoryError - Is there something I can do to help that, apart from splitting the frame into several parts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This problem is most likely related to the usage of **bisplrep** and **bisplev** within **interp2d**. The [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d) mention that they use a smooting factor of **s=0.0** and that **bisplrep** and **bisplev** should be used directly if more control over **s** is needed. The related [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplrep.html#scipy.interpolate.bisplrep) mention that **s** should be found between **(m-sqrt(2*m),m+sqrt(2*m))** where **m** is the number of points used to construct the splines. I had a similar problem and found it solved when using **bisplrep** and **bisplev** directly, where **s** is only optional.

Comment: but this is a linear interpolation, why is the knots of a spline being called?

Comment: how to extrapolate outside the x.y domain using bisplrep and bisplev?

Answer (score 1):

For 2d interpolation,
[griddata](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Gridding_irregularly_spaced_data)
is solid, local, fast.
Take a look at [problem-with-2d-interpolation-in-scipy-non-rectangular-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526514/problem-with-2d-interpolation-in-scipy-non-rectangular-grid) on SO.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at the following interp method in basemap:

mpl_toolkits.basemap.interp
   http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/basemap/doc/html/api/basemap_api.html

unless you really need spline-based interpolation.

Comment: Sorry, that won't help - mpl_toolkits.basemap.interp is only for interpolating one rectilinear grid to another. This condition is not met by my input grid.