# Where to find Natural neighbor interpolation in python

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

Does anyone know of any tools to do a natural neighbor interpolation in python?  unless i'm being stupid, i can't seem to find it in the scipy.interpolate module

Comment: It would help to add the [tag:python] and [tag:scipy] tags.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this would get more response. I'm not really a Python guy, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526514/problem-with-2d-interpolation-in-scipy-non-rectangular-grid) seems to suggest that `griddata` uses natural neighbor interpolation.

Comment: hmmmm nothing still.  I've found the griddata built off the NGL libraries.  I have yet to try it.  then there is the arcGIS arcpy library, that also i have not tried.  When i do i will update

Comment: I suggest you edit what you've tried into your question. That will bump it back onto the front page where hopefully someone who can help will see it.

Comment: well for those interested, i found a library in arcGIS using arcpy, there's also an opensource natural neighbor library called PyNGL.  This library produced the same surface as the arcpy with some different edge effects.  http://www.pyngl.ucar.edu/Download/

Comment: There's also one in the python MetPy package
https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a 3D discrete natural neighbor implementation:

https://github.com/innolitics/natural-neighbor-interpolation

Note that the "discrete" is important here; it is an approximation of the true geometric natural neighbor.

[image]

Comment: Is there a Python code for geometric rather than discrete natural neighbour interpolation?

Comment: I am not aware of a 3D implementation of the geometric natural neighbor in python.

Comment: How about a 2D and geometric implementation?